# Is it allowed to call std::current_exception() in lambda which is called in a catch clause？

Tags: c++, exception

What I mean is something like this:

```
//std::once_flag eptrFlag;
//std::exception_ptr eptr;
//...
try
{
    // may throw exceptions
}
catch (...)
{
    std::call_once(eptrFlag,
    [&]() 
    {
        //...
        eptr = std::current_exception(); 
    });
}
```

Is this undefined behavior, or is it safe?

I've read cppreferences that say:

> If called during exception handling (typically, in a catch clause), captures the current exception object

I'm not sure what is ***during exception handling*** except a normal catch clause, does the closure of the catch block count as ***during exception handling***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, calling `std::current_exception` never causes undefined behaviour.

As for **what is during exception handling**, actually in the language standard exception handling also includes handling an uncaught exception (for instance, 18.1(7) of C++17 standard); for `std::current_exception` the actual condition is “during handling by an active handler an exception”;

An exception handler is active after its catch-clause argument is initialized and until the catch clause argument has just been destroyed.
If there is not currently handled by an active handler an exception, `std:current_exception` will return an empty std::exception_ptr.

Calling functions does not interrupt handling, but it is possible that handing by an active handler another exception will overlap the previous one.

As for, does the lambda function capturing context of the catch block count as **during exception handling**  - in C++ for a lambda function it would be a matter of run-time conditions, it depends on when the function is called, after the handler is complete of before; in you case it is always before; if would called after, `std:current_exception` would return an empty `std::exception_ptr`.

As for using `std::call_once` here, it is not obvious from the piece of the code what exactly you want, but please note that an exception object and exception handling mechanism are thread-local. Even if the catch clause is run in multiple threads, it will never be working with the same exception unless both a reference to the same exception object was passed between threads and copy was not made while rethrowing.
It is implementation-defined whether std::current_exception and std::rethrow_exception make a copy, and you should just consider protection from simultaneous writing if do writing for the case they don’t copy, if don’t want to make you code be a mishmash checking whether it was copied or not and handling the case if not  (though it is possible, there is no any sensible reason for that).

Comment: In my program, exception handling occurs in multiple threads. If an exception occurs, it may occur in multiple threads at the same time. I'm worried about `std::exception_ptr` whether is thread safe or not. If exception handling occurs, I also need to call a `stop()` function to stop these background threads, which only needs to be called once. That's why I used `std::call_once()` here.

Comment: @TianZerL, If you want to stop all the threads after even a single exception, you are totally correct in case you your `eptrFlag` is shared between the threads. 
An `std::exception_ptr` object itself is thread-safe, calling `std::rethrow_exception` itself is thread-safe, but it generally possible that you access the same object when the exception is rethrown (I added corresponded notes to my answer when editing it) - if write into it, you have to protect it by yourself.

Comment: @TianZerL, Also, according to your description of your intentions, it looks like you don’t need to change the exception object - so, there would not be any thread-safeness concern for you here at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to call `std::current_exception()` anywhere within the scope of the `catch` block, even inside of nested function calls.  But once the `catch` block exits, its exception object is no longer valid, unless captured by `std::current_exception()`.